# Removing javascript logo function with a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a page with a logo that changes his color by scrolling the page. I want to keep this function except for some page, so i want to remove this function.

How i could remove the effect if i insert a css class in the code?

```
 var b = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( b > 60 ){       
        $(".navbar").addClass("scroll-fixed-navbar");
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/dark-logo.png');
    } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("scroll-fixed-navbar");
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/white-logo.png');
    }


});




$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";
```

for esample i want to insert if class contain "black", so keep only the dark logo (the previous function will be disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the current javascript with this:

```
if (!$(someElement).hasClass("black")) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

This will prevent the `class="black"` from running that script, I cannot help any further since all your code is not posted but this will certainly point you in the right direction.